# PropertyValueFactory / setCellValueFactory JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I have following basic code in JavaFx. If I want to change the name of PropertyValueFactory("id") to let's say "rid" it does not fill my table anymore. Even if I change the SimpleLongProperty object to rid too. Do you know where the "id" is referencing / pointing to?

public class Main_Controller implements Initializable{

```
    public class Item {
        public SimpleLongProperty id = new SimpleLongProperty();

        public Long getId() {
            return id.get();
        }
    }

    // The table and columns
    @FXML TableView<Item> itemTbl;
    @FXML TableColumn itemIdCol;
    @FXML Button add_Button;

    // The table's data
    ObservableList<Item> data;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // Set up the table data
        itemIdCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Item,Long>("id")
        );

        data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        itemTbl.setItems(data);
    }    

    static long nextId = 1;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        Item item = new Item();
        item.id.setValue(nextId++);
        data.add(item);
    }
}
```

Code With changed PropertyValueFactory:

public class Main_Controller implements Initializable{

```
    public class Item {
        public SimpleLongProperty rid = new SimpleLongProperty();

        public Long getId() {
            return rid.get();
        }
    }

    // The table and columns
    @FXML TableView<Item> itemTbl;
    @FXML TableColumn itemIdCol;
    @FXML Button add_Button;

    // The table's data
    ObservableList<Item> data;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // Set up the table data
        itemIdCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Item,Long>("rid")
        );

        data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        itemTbl.setItems(data);
    }    

    static long nextId = 1;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        Item item = new Item();
        item.rid.setValue(nextId++);
        data.add(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a method in your Item class called

```
public Long getRid(){return rid.get();}
```

or

```
public SimpleLongProperty ridProperty(){return rid;}
```

Note, it's not the name of the variable, which would normally be private, but the name of the getter that matters.

[Javadoc link](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html)

Comment: So it's pointing to the method name. Got you. Thanks!